# How would I display an array of annotations?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, mapkit

I am retrieving an array of longitudes and latitudes from parse, and I want to create x number of annotations based on how many coordinate points there are in the database. I can currently retrieve one, but how would I do it with many? "Coordinates" is an object in parse. Would I have to create an array of MKPointAnnotation? How would I create annotations based on the number retrieved from parse?

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            for objecters in objects!{
                if let latit = objecters["Coordinates"]["Latitude"]{
                    print(lat)
                    self.latitudepoint = latit as! String
                    self.map.reloadInputViews()
                }
                if let longi = objecters["Coordinates"]["Longitude"]{
                    print(long)
                    self.longitudepoint = longi as! String
                     self.map.reloadInputViews()
                }
            }
        }
        let lonlat = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: Double(self.latitudepoint)!,
            longitude: Double(self.longitudepoint)!
        )
      let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = lonlat
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `objects`array will have all the coordinates, you can for each step of this `for objecters in objects!` place the correspondent `MKPointAnnotation` in the Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your array and create annotation for each of the point and add it to the map

```
for objecters in objects!{
    if let latit = objecters["Coordinates"]["Latitude"]{
         self.latitudepoint = latit as! String
         self.map.reloadInputViews()
    }
    else {
        continue
    }
    if let longi = objecters["Coordinates"]["Longitude"]{
         self.longitudepoint = longi as! String
         self.map.reloadInputViews()
    }
    else {
        continue
    }
    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    var coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(self.latitudepoint)!,longitude: Double(self.longitudepoint)!)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

This will add annotations to your map and then you can use `setRegion`property or centre the map at appropriate point.